# Pass an image to Pinterest when creating a pin?

Tags: html, share, urlencode, pinterest

Searched around the web for this but to no avail. Is it possible to pass an image to Pinterest when creating a pin?

Example:
Going to the following URL will create a pin with the URL from "stackoverflow.com" and description "stackoverflow rocks".

http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fc%2F152&description=stackoverflow%20rocks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add an image to a Pinterest pin, just add 'media' onto your string - like this:

http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fc%2F152&description=stackoverflow%20rocks**&media=https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png**

then add the src value from the image, and you're all set.